# How to achieve this bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to code this UI

[image]

so here is my code

```
Scaffold(
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 120,
              child: AppBar(
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Image.asset(notifications, height: 25),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 2)
                ],
                iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0,
              ),
            ),
            const SearchBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: coreColor,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFFE9D2AE)),
        elevation: 0,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book_sharp),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu_book_rounded),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu_book_rounded),
            label: '',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

how do I define customer height on this bottom navigation bar or how to set the container over the bottom navigation bar as per the code?
how did I achieve this UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Overlaying widgets you should use Stack widget,

try this,

```
body: Container(
    color: coreColor,
    child: Stack(
      children: [

        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,left: 0,right: 0,
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
           backgroundColor: coreColor,
            selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFFE9D2AE)),
            elevation: 0,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.book_sharp),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu_book_rounded),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu_book_rounded),
                label: '',
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),

        Positioned(
          top: 0,left: 0,right: 0,bottom: 70,
          child: Container(
            
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: ConstantColor.keyWhiteBackgroundColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(50.0),

              ),
                boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            spreadRadius: 2,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: Offset(0,2), // changes position of shadow
          ),
          ],
            ),
          ),

        )

      ],
    ),
  )
```